# JavaFX Bindings.BindContentbidirectional removes all observableList Contents?

Tags: binding, javafx, observablecollection

i have a problem in JavaFX Binding, I have two observable Lists one of them is static, so when i bind them using (Bindings.bindcontentbidirectional), the two lists get empty and i checked by printing their size and the console shows before binding "List 1 = 3" "List 2 = 0" and after the Bind command the two lists size is ZERO!,so what is the problem??, another question, does it matter in a bidirectional bind who comes in the first parameter???

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is the output "List 1 = 3"? This means the first list has a single element with the value 3? Perhaps post some code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the order of the parameters *does* matter. When creating the `Binding`, the first list will be cleared and filled with the content of the second list. After this point, they will be synchronized bidirectionally as long as the `Binding` exists.

Assuming you did something like `Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(list1, list2)`, your first list has been cleared upon creating the `Binding` because `list2` was empty at that point. So everything went as to be expected.